# How to adjust layouts in xamarin.forms so that it can fit into any phone

Tags: user-interface, layout, xamarin.forms

Hi I am working on a xamarin.forms cross platform app and I am not able to get proper UI If I check the same app on other phone there is misalignment in the buttons.Is there any code that can be used so the buttons look fine in all phones ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making a responsive mobile app UI could actually be a challenge somehow. These two links however, might be helpful:

[Adaptive UI with Xamarin.Forms](https://blog.xamarin.com/adaptive-ui-xamarin-forms/)

[Tips for Building Adaptive Xamarin.Forms Apps](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/tips-for-building-adaptive-xamarin-forms-apps)